# How does blockchain.info resolve adresses?

Tags: blockchain.info, api

I wonder how sites such as *blockchain.info* resolve the owners of public bitcoin addresses. For example, *blockchain.info* knows that the *xkcd* donation address 14FHqYSgA... belongs to *xkcd.com*. It is available at *xkcd.com/bitcoin*, but somebody must be crawling all websites searching for that folder, right?

I assume there is a directory where this kind of websites are stored so that blockchain.info can look it up. Where is it and is there a public API available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no central directory for this information.  You could scrape [the Blockchain list](http://blockchain.info/tags) if you wished, but if you do so you're relying on the accuracy of their information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that many of the blockchain.info public addresses are self reported or crowd reported. There is a link where you can submit an address.